# How to get the claims from the token?

Tags: go, jwt, go-gin

I have a GenerateToken function that generates the token based on Username, Id and the combination of Standard Claims.

```
func GenerateToken( creds *users.User) (tokenString string, err error){
    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(100 * time.Hour)
    claims := &Claims{
        Username: creds.Username,
        Id      : creds.Id,
        StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
            ExpiresAt: expirationTime.Unix(),
            Issuer:    "gogin",
        },
    }
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)
    tokenString, err = token.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("SECRET_CODE")))
    if err != nil{
        return "", err
    }
    return tokenString, nil
}
```

And here is the struct for the Claims

```
type Claims struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Id uint32
    jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

Above will generate me a token.
I need to decode this token and extract the Claims. Is there any way to get the same?

Comment: You mean decode the token string? https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#ParseWithClaims

Comment: @NavidZarepak Yeah, I just need to extract the name as well as Id from the token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func parseToken(tokenString string) (claims jwt.MapClaims, err error) {
    claims = jwt.MapClaims{}
    parsed, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, claims, verifyFunc)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if !parsed.Valid {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid token")
    }
    return claims, nil
}

func verifyFunc(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte(os.Getenv("SECRET_CODE")), nil
}
```

The first method accepts a token string and parses it.
The second method is the key func in which you can use properties in the header of the token